# C# MVC4 bind value with controller variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

new to mvc4 here. I am looking for something like KnockoutJS. How do I able to update the value (i) in my View without refreshing while my controller is running the code? Each time the i increment, I would like my view to be updated. Can anyone guide or give me some tutorial/reference link? I don't know what is this called. Thank you.

```
public ActionResult Increment()
{
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        // Display i value in View without Refreshing
    }
}
```

Comment: _"while my controller is running the code"_ - don't do heavy work or "background processes" in action methods. You _could_ use a session variable and an AJAX request that retrieves this value at certain intervals.

Comment: You don't seem to understand how client-side and server-side code works in web development.  While the controller is running code, nothing is displayed in the browser at all.  It isn't until the controller *returns a response* that a page even exists.

Comment: hi there, so what should I use for such heavy work?

Comment: @Maki92: Depends on what the system should be doing.  What is this "heavy work"?

Comment: hi @David, that is my problem.. I am thinking of using jQuery or Ajax to update the value. I am looking for a solution or guide for this problem

Comment: @Maki92: We can't guide you if you can't describe the problem.  If all you need to do is "update a value" then that can be entirely done in JavaScript with no need to involve server-side code at all.

Comment: @David, I have a TCP Connection which receiving messages from an Agent. I would like the message to be displayed on my view via live-update behaviour.

Comment: @Maki92: In that case you're probably looking for a tool like SignalR, which specializes in keeping a communication channel open from the server to the client for live updates.  Server-side you probably wouldn't have a hard loop in a controller action, but might have some background worker of some sort instead.

Comment: I only need to keep the connection open with the Agent only when the user is on that Page. For such case, I should use background worker? Thanks for helping and explaining :)

Answer (score 0):

Views display the results of Actions.

If you want a live-update behaviour, look at something like SignalR.

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look here:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr

or here for the beginning:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr?bcsi_scan_4deb7c0df8351b78=WgvHo5O5MWe1Fnj+1DbyNYdXM4wyAAAAr5dKRg==

Microsofts tutorial of using Signal R and pushing Information to a / multiple view(s)

Comment: Thank you for the guidelines.. Appreciate it very much :)